# JSJaC+Openfire works only local

Tags: apache, xmpp, openfire, jsjac

so far I developed completey locally, having everything (Apache, Openfire, JSJaC application) on my laptop, running quite fine. Now I want to use remote server for Apache/Openfire. I did basically the same steps, incl. the whole http-bind stuff. I test the setting with simpleclient.html provided by JSJaC.

Now here's the deal, if I use the simpleclient directly on the remote server - e.g., http://here.domain.org/simpleclient.html - it works. If I use it locally - e.g., http://[local_machine]/simpleclient.html - and with the same settings I get an 503 (service unavailable). It seems to be more a network/Apache issue than Openfire/JSJaC one, but I'm not an expert.

My parameters for the simpleclient:

- HTTP Base:      http://here.domain.org/http-bind/
- JabberServer:   here.domain.org

So in my apache virtual host conf file I have the lines:

- AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
- ProxyReqests On
- ProxyPass /http-bind/ http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/

So basically the http bind works since I can connect when the simpleclient.html resides on the server. What I tried so far:

- checked if 7070 open from extern: yes
- checked etc/hosts - here the relevant lines

  - 127.0.0.1  localhost
  - 123.123.123.123   here.domain.org  here
- checked Apache conf for restrictions: can't find any, basically i have an "Allow from all" everywhere (but I'm not completely sure where to look at)

By the way, with,e.g., Pidgin I can connect from my laptop to the remote server. Just the JSJaC simpleclient won't do. So I assume it's the http-bind that causes the trouble. I would understand if port 7070 weren't open, but it is.

Any hints or help are much appreciated!

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. It was a cross-domain scripting issue. I started looking into the JSJaC library and noticed that it makes XmlHttpRequests which by default won't work across different domains. I therefore had to allow this with Apache on the Openfire-Server. I added the follwing entries in the VirtualHost conf file:

```
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, *"
```

Of course the `mod_headers` module must be loaded for this.

I'm not sure which entries are actually required, I didn't try every combinations. I *think* the `always` is needed since the request to the http-bind address is a proxy thingy.